# Removing everything but an interval of values from a list in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, list, intervals

I have a list

```
Dim list as New List(Of Double)
```

It contains values from 0 to 1000. I want to keep the values within the interval [360 ; 720].
The following code works for me, but I am sure that there is a more efficient way:

```
Dim index As Integer

Do
    list.RemoveAt(index)
Loop Until list(index) > 360

For i = list.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If list(i) > 720 Then
        list.RemoveAt(i)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Do you mean to keep the values that are 360-720, or keep the data in list indexes 360-720 ?

Comment: The values that are actually 360-720, not the indices

Comment: Forgot to mention that: they are sorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a one-liner:

```
list = list.Where(Function(x) x > 360 AndAlso x <= 720).ToList()
```

If you're *sure* the list is sorted, you could also do this, which might run faster:

```
list = list.
    SkipWhile(Function(x) x <= 360).
    TakeWhile(Function(x) x <= 720).
    ToList()
```

Comment: Your one-liner was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your list appears to be sorted, and List supports [RemoveRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removerange?view=net-5.0)

```
list.RemoveRange(721, list.Count - 721)
list.RemoveRange(0, 360)
```

If it's not a sequential list (no 1:1 mapping of index:value) you could IndexOf to find the indexes of the values, then RemoveRange based on those:

```
Dim st = list.IndexOf(360)
Dim ed = list.LastIndexOf(720)
list.RemoveRange(ed + 1, list.Count - ed - 1)
list.RemoveRange(0, st)
```

The answers that are proposing Linq have a notable difference to yours; your code permamently alters the original list; LINQ doesn't do this

All this said, it'd probably be more effective to just generate a new range (based on the assumption that you have 1001 incrementing ints in a list and want 360 - 720):

```
Enumerable.Range(360, 361).ToList()
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It appears to me, that you misunderstood my question. I do NOT want to remove everything but the indices 360-720. I want to delete the values outside of 360-720.

For example
list(19)=340
list(20)=360
....
list(28)=720
list(29)=750

So I want to delete list(0) to list (19) and list(29) to the end of the list. Sorry for not beeing precisely here.

Comment: You said your list contains the values from 0 to 1000, but in any case, I mentioned that if it doesn't, then you can use IndexOf to find the indexes where you should start and stop..

Comment: yes, so list(0) could be 0 and list(last_index) could be 1000. Thank you, I give it a shot

Comment: Not sure I understood the add, but I made an edit to suggest looking for the 360 and the 720 using [Last]IndexOf and then Removerange.. I think the maths is right, but check it's not off-by-1